# Aligned access to array elements

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-alignment

For some reason (data resides in virtual memory of boost/interprocess/file_mapping.hpp) I write my own memory allocation. To achieve cross-platform portability I concern about memory alignment of generic `T`. (Note `T` is strongly POD or simple C++ scalar like `char` or `int`)
From example in
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage
we can see following code:

```
...
typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type data[N];
std::size_t m_size = 0;

public:
   // Create an object in aligned storage
    template<typename ...Args> void emplace_back(Args&&... args) 
    {
       if( m_size >= N ) // possible error handling
            throw std::bad_alloc{};
       new(data+m_size) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
.....
```

So instead of regular access `data[i]` I have always evaluate aligned address.

So my question:

1) Isn't it overhead? And I can just allocate and access memory for `(sizeof(data[N]))`

2) If it is overhead what the reason to use aligned access shown in example?

Comment: I think we need a more complete example, but the code I see now seem to be calling placement new for each object, which is useful if they are objects, and with sufficient inlining would become "nearly nothing". As always with "is this slower than ideal", you really have to measure that, not just look at code in theory, since compilers sometimes are very clever and sometimes not, based on tiny details.

Comment: The example static vector class at cppreference contains an array of char to store the data. There is no alignment gurantee for chars, or char arrays. If you now try to store a double at the arbitrarily aligned array address (i.e. one which is not at a, say, 4 byte boundary), the program may crash. Therefore, as @Revolver correctly points out, the char array must start at an address which is suitably aligned for the type (and will make all future elements in it properly aligned, too, without padding, actually).

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't it overhead?

Maybe. Maybe not. For majority of types, I expect `aligned_storage::type` size to be equal to contained type size. And I would expect compiler to optimize access to be no worse than raw array access.

> I can just allocate and access memory for `(sizeof(data[N]))`
>   If it is overhead what the reason to use aligned access shown in example?

Yes, you can allocate raw memory (by using `char` array, for example) but you have to make sure that it is properly aligned for type you are using. It is not easy, if you want to store some uninitializated array by value or to allocate some memory on stack. Or if you are using custom memory allocator which does not use `new`/`malloc` and do not have their aligment properties.

`aligned_storage` structure is a helper to automate stuff you would write yourself otherwise.

Comment: "For majority of types, I expect aligned_storage::type size to be equal to contained type size": Thats a funny assumption. This class exists *specifically* for the cases when, for what reason ever, the native alignment is not sufficient for the program's needs. That implies that at least on the original platform chances are close to 1 that the storage size is larger than the contianed type size.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider , I have to disagree. I usually see this class used when you need raw storage for some type, which will be filled later by placement new. In provided snippet you can see that that template arguments for aligment is `alignof(T)`, which cannot introduce more overhead than raw arrays (and even single object due to how object size and position of array elements correlate) would. And if you actually look at the complete code, you can see that `aligned_storage` is used exactly like simple storage.

Comment: Upon closer inspection of the example I see that you are right. Alignment is needed for the internal data array only, and it's just the alignment requirement of the element type, not more, not less, like with a std vector, but fixed size. So yes, I change my mind and would contend that chances are 1 that there is no overhead ;-).